# How to read XML data from SQL Server into PHP

Tags: php, xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert a number of SQL Server FOR XML queries and XSL Templates, from a legacy ASP application to PHP.
Basically the app assembles an XML document from several queries then uses the XSL template to output HTML.

I have being reading this blog post:

- [Consuming SQL Server Result Sets as XML with PHP (Jul 2011 by Brian Swan)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/07/26/consuming-sql-server-result-sets-as-xml-with-php.aspx)

I am using `sqlsrv_query()` followed by `sqlsrv_fetch()` and `sqlsrv_get_field()` to get the data. The result set is returned by default as an *XML stream*.

I can't figure out how to read the stream into a `DOMDocument` object. I guess I can convert the output to a string, then parse the string into the object, but how do you read the XML stream directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fetching the data by hinting the PHP-data-type as shown in the blog-post you've linked:

```
$xml = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING('UTF-8'));
```

Then the variable `$xml` contains an UTF-8 encoded string. Strings in PHP are always binary and UTF-8 is the default encoding of an XML document. This is the same in PHP: *DOMDocument* in PHP expects all input strings to be UTF-8 encoded (as outlined in the [*Introduction<sup>Docs</sup>*](http://www.php.net/intro.dom)).

All you need to do is to [load the XML as string<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/domdocument.loadxml):

```
$doc   =  new DOMDocument();
$result = $doc->loadXML($xml);
```

You can then verify if this works by checking the return value and outputting the XML as string from the document:

```
var_dump($result);          # should be (boolean) TRUE
$doc->save('php://output'); # should be your XML verbatim
```

this should do it, let me know if you use a different way to fetch from the database. Because then this might work differently, e.g. if you are getting [a *PHP Stream<sup>Docs</sup>*](http://www.php.net/intro.stream.php) you might want to use [*`stream_get_contents()`<sup>Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/stream_get_contents) to convert the stream into a string first. You can *not* load streams with *DOMDocument* in PHP, this is why you need to convert it first to a string.

See as well:

- [Default PHP Data Types - SQL Server 2008 R2<sup>*MSDN*</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296193.aspx)
- [How to: Specify PHP Data Types - SQL Server 2008 R2<sup>*MSDN*</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296208.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought there might be a way to import the stream directly. The XML datasets are quite small, so I guess the overhead of converting to string and parsing that should be small.

Comment: AFAIK importing the stream directly is not possible. I wish it would, for example with [`XMLReader`](http://php.net/XMLReader), but like with `DOMDocument` this is not possible (however it was never really an issue for me practically, it's just a bit a pity it's not possible).

Comment: I agree, however, I have now managed to get my XML document constructed by converting the output to strings. Thanks again for your help.